# Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): user.associateSoftwareToken is not a function

Tags: aws-amplify

I am trying to setup MFA for user using `aws-amplify`. Ran into this error while getting the secret code.

Below is my code:

```
async function getCode(user) {
  let code = await Auth.setupTOTP(user);
  return code;
}

useEffect(() => {
  if(location.search) {
    let username = new URLSearchParams(location.search).get("user");
    let issuer = new URLSearchParams(location.search).get("issuer");
    let code = getCode(username);
  }
```

Error:

[image]

Please advice, Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was passing the wrong value to it. It's shouldn't be just `username` but rather the whole `CognitoUser` object.

Correct way:

```
async function getCode() {
   let user = await Auth.currentAuthenticatedUser();
   let code = await Auth.setupTOTP(user);
   return code;
}
```